# Good practice of exception hierarchy in C#

Tags: c#, exception

Now I write C# code after the PHP.

In PHP I create a hierarchy of exceptions guided by the recommendations of the Zend Framework(Symfony now use something similar).

In package(for example Order) I create folder Exception, in this folder(translate from php to C#):

```
namespace Order.Exception
{
    interface ExceptionInterface{}
    class ApplicationException : System.ApplicationException, ExceptionInterface{}
    class OrderNotFoundException : ApplicationException {}
    class SomethingHappensException : ApplicationException{}
}
```

I need a lot of exceptions(relatively) to conveniently express the things from domain.

Is there any have good practices to create hierarchies of exceptions?

Technical details of creation I understand completely. The issue of good practice.

Comment: Use built-in ones or create custom.  Handle them by specificity - most specific first, least specific last.  Don't get to crazy with inheritance or interfaces it will just make it more complicated than it has to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two quotes from *CLR via C#, 4th Edition*:

> If you want to define an exception type hierarchy, it is highly
> recommended that the hierarchy be  shallow and wide in order to create
> as few base classes as possible. The reason is that base classes act
> as a way of treating lots of errors as one error, and this is usually
> dangerous.
>
> (...)
>
> There are versioning ramifications here, too. If you define a new
> exception type  derived from an existing exception type, then all code
> that catches the existing base type  will now catch your new type as
> well. In some scenarios, this may be desired and in some  scenarios,
> it may not be desired. The problem is that it really depends on how
> code that  catches the base class responds to the exception type and
> types derived from it. Code that  never anticipated the new exception
> may now behave unpredictably and open security  holes. The person
> defining the new exception type can’t know about all the places where
> the base exception is caught and how it is handled. And so, in
> practice, it is impossible to  make a good intelligent decision here.